# Logical test to determine whether a cell is part of a named range

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

So I've searched the web and stack overflow, and I haven't been able to find anything on this, mostly because my problem has two parts. First part is: logical test to see if a cell is part of a named range, but we aren't able to narrow it down to one named range, because there are multiple named ranges on my spreadsheet. Second part is, once I know the cell is in a named range, I want to know the name of that range.

Im thinking I would make a for loop made of an array of Named Range objects, but I also dont really know how to do that. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Gary's Student answer is correct, it doesn't address this need:

> ...but we aren't able to narrow it down to one named range, because there are multiple named ranges on my spreadsheet

For that you will need to iterate the Names collection as you guessed.

Here's a modified version that should do the iteration over each Named Range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SO_Example()
    Dim myCell As Range: Set myCell = Range("A1") 'this is the cell you want to test
    Dim nm As Name 'this is a Name Range object

    'Iterate the names in the workbook
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        'Use the RefersTo property to get a range object.
        'Refers to adds a '=' sign, which causes an issue so that's why the replace is here
        'There is a probably a cleaner way to do this :)
        Dim nameRng As Range: Set nameRng = Range(Replace(nm.RefersTo, "=", ""))

        'Check to see if the ranges intersect
        If Not Intersect(myCell, nameRng) Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print nm.Name & " address is " & nm.RefersToLocal & " Intersects myCell at " & myCell.Address
        Else
            Debug.Print nm.Name & " address is " & nm.RefersToLocal & " Does not Intersect myCell at " & myCell.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Example Output:**

```
Another_Name address is =Sheet1!$M$5 Does not Intersect myCell at $A$1
Name1 address is =Sheet1!$A$1 Intersects myCell at $A$1
Name2 address is =Sheet1!$A$1:$A$2 Intersects myCell at $A$1
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution, I think this is exactly what I was looking for !!!

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a Named Range like:

[image]

This code:

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("HomeOnTheRange"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "active cell is not on HomeOnTheRange"
    Else
        MsgBox "active cell is on HomeOnTheRange"
    End If
End Sub
```

will tell you if the `ActiveCell` is on it.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that the same cell might belong to multiple range names.
When looping through range names you can use either workbook names or worksheet names. Worksheet names are not visible on workbook level.
The below is addition to above answers.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iCell As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim nRng as Range

Set iCell = ws.Cells(5, 8)

For Each rngName In ws.Names
    Set nRng = ws.Range(rngName)
    Set r = Intersect(iCell, nRng)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "active cell is on " & ws.Range(rngName).NAME
    End If
Next rngName
```

Comment: The way I will be setting up the spreadsheet, the cells i am going through will only belong to one named range.

Comment: Oh, I see your point, I should probably specify that I only want ws specific names. Thank you !

Comment: My pleasure. It was just a note in case others look for solution here. Depending on whether your range names are on workbook level or worksheet level you can use respective loop.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one off scenario, I first just want to make sure you checked the name manager in excel by going to:

Formulas > Defined Names > Name Manager
(You can also press Ctrl + F3)

Once in the name manager you can sort be named range (if that's what you're after) or by "Refers To," which might also be helpful.

Assuming that's been checked off, here is an attempt to elaborate on Gary's Student's answer via an array comprised of named range candidates:

```
Dim PossibleRanges
PossibleRanges = Array("2014Sales", "PossibleRange1", "BeyonceGreatestHits")
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 2 <~~~~~~~ (note the first elmement in the array is indexed at 0)
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(PossibleRanges(i))) Is Nothing Then
    Else MsgBox("Activecell is part of " & PossibleRanges(i))
    End If
Next i
```

I'm still very new to this, so I apologize if there is any issue with the above. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I can definitely see how that would be useful in some scenarios :)